# Keep Unpermitted parameters from printing to log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

Is there a way to stop unpermitted params from printing to my logs? Its just a huge mess and making it hard to look thru the unpermitted params in order to find issues.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check out the [lograge](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge) gem. By default it will not log any parameters but there is some example code in the README to show how you can add logging for the params you want.

Comment: awesome, glad I'm not the only one drowning in Ruby's logs